# php isset($_post[]) and javascript form.submit

Tags: javascript, php, html

for some reason  isset($_post) doesn't work when i use js form.submit()
how i can resolve that without changing  type of input from button to submit and just with using vanilla javascript because i need both of them.

code html:

```
<form name="user_verification" action="action.php" method="POST">
 Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)" name="button" value="submit">
</form>
```

and here is the php script in action.php file

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")
{
if(isset($_POST['button'])) 
{
echo 'yes';
}else{
echo 'no';
}
}
```

and here is the javascript in action.js file

```
function myFunction(button)
{
//some code
const form=button.parentNode;
form.submit();}
```

Comment: What output are u getting? “No” or blank?

Comment: You have a typo - function spelling in `onclick="myFucntion(this)"` should be `onclick="myFunction1(this)"

Comment: i am getting no output, sorry i mistyped the name of function when writing post here. i will update

Comment: @Tushar now I cleared all the typos please feel free to test it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the problem didn't raise from the PHP. Buttons' value is sent when the form is directly submitted by them (In this case, it seems impossible).

**Suggestion 1:** use another field to check form submission.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
        echo 'yes';
    } else {
        echo 'no';
    }
}
```

**Suggestion 2:** add hidden input in the HTML.

```
<form name="user_verification" action="test.php" method="POST">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="button" value="submit">
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)">
</form>
```

**Suggestion 3:** change button type to hidden before submitting.

```
function myFunction(button) {
    // some code
    button.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    const form=button.parentNode;
    form.submit();
    button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
}
```

Comment: the third solution is the most interesting one.Thank you